# What is the benifit of High-Resolution on a Notebook Display?

Tags: mac, resolution

I've recently been reading some articles and some discussion going on around the MacBook Pro i5 and i7.

Some people had said that they wanted to purchase the 15" over the 13" *just* because of the high resolution display upgrade (From a stock 1440 x 900 to an 1680 x 1050 upgrade matte option.)

I'm quite confused about the decision. Why would someone want to do this? Wouldn't the toolbars and default 12 point text be so small that they'll ruin your eyes in little time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's an alternative to those of us who don't want to purchase an external monitor, or whose monitors are already in use elsewhere. For me, now that I've begun playing with Blender and Unity3D, and do quite a bit of Photoshop work, having a 1680x1050 display would really help a lot. Regarding the text and toolbars, I don't see most UI elements on the Mac being an issue there. I can scale the desktop and Dock icons accordingly, and I can zoom in a browser to make (what is easily the majority of the text I read on a computer) things more legible.

It's a trade-off, like anything else.

Now I want the 15" MacBook. Thanks! :)

Answer (score 1):

- Because it's pretty.
- Because it's a feature.
- Because everyone likes a bigger screen.
- Because everyone likes a higher resolution.

Pardon my cynicism but even I would like it were I not so painfully aware of the practical implications, such as battery life.

Answer (score 1):

higher resolution = more stuff on screen = less window switching

also consider this: if you are used to reading things written/pressed on paper, how does that paper look like? right: it's much higher than it is wide. Now look at your screen: it's the opposite. Look at this site: in a full screen browser, there's tons of unused screen space at the edges. I like screens with a lot of vertical resolution: it looks like what I'm used for reading to and it's less scrolling.